# What can cause my motorcycle to shift into gear (but not all of them) without using the clutch?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, clutch, shifting, cb600

I'm riding a Honda CB600F Hornet built 2006 (last model with carbs). I put it away for the fall/winter about 6 months ago. This week I was doing the maintenance, cleaned the brakes, lubed cables, synchronized carbs, changed the oil etc.

I noticed accidently I could put it into gear (first, second etc.), **without** using the clutch, **while running.** Obviously this isn't right, so I checked cable freeplay, tried readjusting, didn't really make a difference.

After some fiddling around (possibly due to cable adjustment?) I can't put it into first gear at all anymore (not even with clutch), but I goes up to 4th **without** the cluth again. 5th and 6th won't work at all. If it shifts, it will stay in gear though, so the clutch isn't slipping. Is it sticking? I'm thinking of opening the transmission and checking the plates etc. but I'd rather avoid this if another option is available.

Very strange situation, I'm not sure what can be causing this, especially because I didn't have this problem when I put it away for the winter...

Could this be the transmission plates that need replacing? I'm sure I put in the correct amount and type of oil.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:  To clarify, this behavior occurs while the engine is running**

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking that you can indeed shift into gear without using the clutch on a motorbike? In other words, you should be able to upshift and downshift whilst driving, without using the clutch. That's obviously something that's likely to hurt your transmission though. P.S. Great tagging work on this question! :)

Comment: @JoErNanO I think its mechanically possible, but you'd have to match gearbox and engine speeds (RPM). Pretty sure this is quite difficult and like you said, not something you want to do on a regular basis. There are also aftermarket "quickshifters" which basically clutch for you, but I don't have one of those installed :)

Comment: @DucatiKiller Idle, as in, engine running but in neutral? Doesn't seem to explain why it won't shift into 5th/6th or first gear though.

Comment: To clarify, the whole clutching/shifting problem is while the engine is **running**.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Haven't tried it, because I can't get it reliably in first gear. Why do you ask?

Comment: Yes its been on stands the whole time, [here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2lehklV9HY&feature=youtu.be) of the most recent attempt. Turn your sound down a bit. Note the grinding near the end? After this the gear got stuck and i had to clutch multiple times and use my hands to free the wheel because it wouldn't turn anymore.

Comment: In the video, the bik was warmed up though and I managed to upshift all the way. After cooling down, shifting no longer worked (like before...)

Comment: Havent tried this yet, but I have a feeling you could be right about the whole "chasing ghosts". I have an idea I'm gonna try this weekend... Keep you posted.

Comment: I'm gonna try that tomorrow, the clutch cable is disassembled and the clutch cover is off. Got a day off tomorrow to put everything together and try. Honestly, the more I think about it, the more I think its nothing since I can upshift while the engine is off (by moving the wheel slightly) - explaining the mesh transmission you mentioned. Gonna check with the engine running tomorrow.

Comment: @DucatiKiller So I tried your test today, with the engine running, wheel spinning free. Pulled in the clutch, rear brake applied, wheel stopped turning. Not sure what this means, seems perfectly normal? I can still upshift without using the clutch while its running though...

Comment: @JosephD. you can speed shift upshift if you want.I simply wanted to validate that your clutch was not an issue as it was mentioned.  I think you have bent shift forks IF the bike is shifting on it's own.  So, my last question.  Does the bike shift on it's own?  Just validating what I think I'm reading.

Comment: @DucatiKiller On its own,no, I meant I can upshift whenever i want without using the clutch. What do you mean with "speed shift"?

Comment: @JosephD. Speed shift is slang for shifting without the clutch.

Comment: Which is fine to do if you do it correctly.

Comment: @JosephD.  I believe I over complicated the question.  From the title and some other verbiage I assumed the bike was changing gears on it's own without any rider input.  Ii would be nice if we could delete all of the comments and you could clarify your question and we start over.  Sorry about my assumption.

Comment: @DucatiKiller No worries, I appreciate you taking the effort to work with me. I think the misunderstanding was due to some limited knowledge on my part. Since shifting gears when the engine's off seems to work as intended, the question that remains is, is it normal that you can upshift **while running**, without using the clutch? I'm pretty sure I'm not "speedshifting", I basically just upshift with the pedal at a random rate. And if it is normal, whats the point of the clutch at all?

Comment: If the bike is on a stand when you do it (rear wheel in the air) that's fine.  If you have your throttle pegged wide open and are accelerating and you can do it without backing off the throttle.  That would be odd, as the transmission is loaded up with the torque from the motor running wide open.  You could force it and it might work but that would usually cause incremental transmission damage over time that would eventually give you a condition of the bike falling out of gear under various circumstances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39408/discussion-between-ducatikiller-and-joseph-d).

Comment: Click on that chat link above for us to communicate with.  It'll work just like comments but there won't be comment sprawl all of the question.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: @DucatiKiller check your latest chat message ;) I'll write a more elaborate response asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any motorcyle you CAN shift into gear without using the clutch, you have to match the engine speed with the output speed, many people use it for racing, and if done correctly does not cause excesive wear, but for normal use, it is not recommended.

now when you say it wont shift into gear, do you mean the shifter just come to a halt before the shift engages? or does it go all the way through but you dont feel the thump of it shifting? Does your motorcycle have a gear indicator? does it indicate the upshift?

What I guess is the problem, you either have the clutch badly adjusted, if it is partially clutched you may burn the pads and have trouble shifting and low speed output.

If it is too loose, then the lever does not engage the clutch completely.

Also, do an engine oil change, make sure it is the correct and the correct amount.

If all fails, then an inspection of the clutch may be in order.